# I need a formula with these outputs.

Tags: geometry, circles

I need a formula for when i put in a value for k it gives me an output. Here are the outputs I know, but I need everything in between 0 to 259. It should be a circle. (I'm making a game that has a third person view that spins around when the player changes their yaw and I'm 14 so i don't know how to do this yet)

if k=0 then x=0 and z=5

if k=90 then x=5 and z=0

if k=180 then x=0 and z=-5

if k=-90 then x=-5 and z=0

Comment: Look up functions $\sin$ and $\cos$ in whatever basic math library your programming language has. You'll most likely have $x=5 \cdot \sin \frac k {2 \pi}$ and $z=5 \cdot \cos \frac k {2 \pi}$.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, but i am using Java and i know how to the sin and cos functions but i dont know what they do. I'm just asking for a quick formula or something.

Comment: Well, then `x = 5 * java.lang.Math.sin((2*java.lang.Math.PI)*k/360.0)` and something similar for z (sorry my formula was wrong in last comment). It would be good for you to understand what these functions do. But I'll just link to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Relation_to_the_unit_circle).

Answer (score 1):

Here are the formulas, written in degrees:

$$x= 5*\cos(90-k), \ \ y=5*\sin(90-k) $$

(they take into account the fact that you move clockwise on the circle, beginning at 90°).

Comment: you might need a prior conversion of your angles into radians (the natural unit in mathematics), with conversion factor:

$$deg=3.1416/180 \ \ \text{(have you recognized} \ \pi \ \text{)? And then} $$

$$x=5*\cos((90-k)*deg), \ \ y=5*\sin((90-k)*deg).$$

Comment: The angle is called $k$, not $x$.

Comment: @Karolis Juodelé Thanks for your acute eye !